# Flow chart using Userform in Excel

Tags: excel, userform, flowchart

I have a Userform to create a flow chart. How to repeat insertion of shapes using `commandbutton1` and to move the box at a equidistant location ie. how to repeat the `if statements` until `commandbutton1` is pressed?

This code is only selecting the first shape, and I'd like to insert shapes on the click of `cmdbutton1`.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()   
    If OptionButton1 = True Then    
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(1, 68, 99, 136, 57).Select     
        Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value    
        Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText
        UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = ""   
    ElseIf OptionButton2 = True Then   
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(9, 68, 99, 136, 57).Select
        Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value
        Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText
        UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = ""   
    ElseIf OptionButton3 = True Then   
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(2, 68, 99, 136, 57).Select
        Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value
        Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText
        UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = ""
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 135.75, 120, 135.5, 165).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadTriangle
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Perhaps you could read the coordinates of the currently selected object, and create a new object adjacent to that? It's not clear what the OptionButtonX tests are for though, or whether they are relevant to your question.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for design ideas, which is rather broad.  I would suggest you decide _how_ the app will work, and explain what the options buttons are if they are relevant, and then make an attempt to break down the cloning logic into achievable pieces of work.